The center of the finitary matrix algebra
Let $ R $ be an unital associative ring, and let $ n $ be a positive integer. It is well-established that the center of the full matrix ring $\mathrm{M}_n(R)$ is
$$
\{ \lambda \mathrm{I}_n \mid \lambda \in Z(R) \},
$$
where $Z(R)$ denotes the center of $R$.
Consider $\mathrm{M}_\infty(R)$, the set of all infinite matrices with only finitely many nonzero entries. For any matrix $A \in \mathrm{M}_\infty(R)$, we can express $A$ as
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
A' & \\ 
& 0 
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $A' \in \mathrm{M}_n(R)$ for some $n$. In this case, $n$ can be chosen such that $n > 1$ and $A'$ is singular.
With the usual definitions of addition and multiplication, it appears that $\mathrm{M}_\infty(R)$ forms a non-unital associative ring, and its center is
$
\{0\}.
$
I am seeking confirmation of this conclusion and would appreciate any validation of the claim.

Yes, and this actually follows from your claim about the center of $M_n(R)$. Every element of $M_{\infty}(R)$ is an element of the non-unital subring $M_n(R)$ for some $n$, meaning it does not commute with some element of $M_{n+1}(R)$ (unless it's zero), since as an element of $M_{n+1}(R)$ its last row and column are zero so it can't be a nonzero scalar multiple of the identity.
